# Control file creation failed

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I lost all the control files and I don't have backup for it. Control file creation failed

```
SQL> CREATE CONTROLFILE SET DATABASE "UAT02" RESETLOGS NOARCHIVELOG
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 2
MAXDATAFILES 30
MAXINSTANCES 1
MAXLOGHISTORY 292
LOGFILE
GROUP 1 '/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/redo01.log' SIZE 100M,
GROUP 2 '/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/redo02.log' SIZE 100M,
-- STANDBY LOGFILE
DATAFILE
'/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/system01.dbf' size 400m',
'/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 300m,
CHARACTER SET US7ASCII
; 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "UAT02" RESETLOGS NOARCHIVELOG
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
ORA-01565: error in identifying file '/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/system01.dbf
size 400m'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
System01.dbf is there
```

[oracle@localhost uat02]$ ls -ltr

```
total 1034612
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 104858112 Sep 27 07:41 redo02.log
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 104865792 Sep 27 11:48 undo01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 419438592 Sep 27 11:48 system01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 314580992 Sep 27 11:48 sysaux01.dbf
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 104858112 Sep 27 11:48 redo01.log
-rw-r----- 1 oracle oinstall 9748480 Sep 28 23:39 control01.ctl
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you logged in as the right userid/groupid? Any file permissions issue? Check with your SA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the comma at the end of sysaux01.dbf, is the cause

DATAFILE

```
'/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/system01.dbf' size 400m,
'/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 300m,
```

and also I have added undotablespace details as well. These change allowed me to create the controlfile

Answer (score 0):

Your single quote is in the wrong place in the datafile definition:

```
DATAFILE
'/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/system01.dbf' size 400m,
'/opt/oracle/oradata/uat02/sysaux01.dbf' SIZE 300m,
```

Comment: I have changed the single quote. Still the same issue